# How to dynamically group options in <select> into optgroups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `<select>` that is dynamically populated. I need to partially group those options into `<optgroup>` tags/ The code in simplified case is:

**html:**

```
<select id="mySelect" size="9">
</select>
<h1>how to add them with code only?</h1>
```

**JS:**

```
var opt = [
        {name:"somefriend1"},
        {name:"somefriend2"},
        {name:"someother1", tag: 'other'},
        {name:"someother2", tag: 'other'},
        {name:"somerequest1", tag: 'request'},
        {name:"somerequest2"},
        {name:"somesent1", tag: 'request'},
        {name:"somesent2"}
];

$(function(){
    var $select = $('#mySelect');
    $.each(opt, function(index){
            $('<option />').html(this.name).appendTo($select);
            // TODO: group into 
    });
});
```

As a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6e478sd/10/).

Expected result:

```
<select id="mySelect" size="9">
  <option>somefriend1</option>
  <option>somefriend2</option>
  <optgroup label="other">
    <option>someother1</option>
    <option>someother2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="request">
    <option>somerequest1</option>
    <option>somesent1></option>
  </optgroup>
  <option>somerequest2</option>
  <option>somesent2</option>
</select>
<h1>how to add them with code only?</h1>
```

My full situation is: i have a `<select>` that is being generated with help of knockout.js like this:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $data.options, optionsText: 'name', optionsAfterRender: $data.setOptionDisable, value: $data.cur"></select>
```

I would like to use `optionsAfterRender` callback to group options appropriately while `<select>` is being generated.

Edit: dreadfully sorry, i have messed up m jsfiddle and one i was using as base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there would be a need to do some DOM manipulation to get what you you are looking for, this could work for you...

```
 self.setTagGroup=function(option, item)
    {
        if(item.tag)
        {
            var grp =$(option).parent("select").find("[label="+item.tag+"]");
            if(grp.length==0)
            {
                grp = $("<optGroup></optGroup>");
                grp.attr("label",item.tag);
                $(option).parent("select").append(grp);
            }
            grp.append($(option));
        }
    }
```

and in the mark up

```
<select size="8" data-bind="options: users, optionsText: 'name', optionsAfterRender: setTagGroup, value: selectedUser"></select>
```

the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/m6e478sd/13/

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be just what i need

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rework this with just knockout, no jQuery (also, the `optionsAfterRender` was unnecessary):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP4E9/36/

I had to add a custom `bindingHandler` definition, but otherwise it's pretty straightforward. I also had to reformat the `opt` data object to lend itself to the nested `foreach` loops, but it's essentially the same.

```
<select id="mySelect" size="9" data-bind="foreach: opt, value: selectedOption">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: options">
        <option data-bind="text: name, option: name"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Very cool ... one thing tho, why did you add the option custom bindingHandler?

Comment: I had seen it elsewhere, and it made it easier to set the value of the select object (see the `ko.selectExtensions.writeValue(element, value)`; line)

Comment: This way all options end in `optgroup>`-s. I want some of them to be outside `<optgroup>` tags; that's why in my example not every element has a tag.

Comment: you can't use a mix like that. if you're using `optgroup`, they all have to be wrapped. you didn't have any outside in your example, either.

Comment: Fixed my example. And html allows options to be outside `optgroup` just fine